# How to configure mongoid 1.9.2 on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I have a rails 2.3.8 app running on heroku, but am having trouble configuring mongoid 1.9.2 with MongoHQ. Has anyone made this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To connect to the database you must use the `MONGODB_URL` variable.

```
# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  <<: *defaults
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Also, make sure the `host` property is not set in the `defaults` node.**strong text**

```
defaults: &defaults
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019
```

Comment: As far as I can tell mongoid 1.9.2 does not know about the uri configuration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could create a MongoHQ account and code the db settings instead of using the ENV variables if you wanted. So same as you'd do with a traditional db setup. I.e.